# is there a way to completely delete Chrome OS on a chromebook - and install linux (not dual boot)

Tags: linux, chromebook

I'm looking to buy the latest fanless HP or Samsung Chromebooks.  However, I want to install linux on it and delete Chrome OS - is there a way to do this ?

I am familiar with Crouton and Chrubuntu - however, they seem only to provide dual boot solutions

many thanks

Comment: I used this on my Pixel and it worked well first time. http://lifehacker.com/how-to-install-linux-on-a-chromebook-and-unlock-its-ful-509039343

Answer (score 3):

I had flashed u-boot on Samsung Chromebook and completely formatted the internal MMC. I have archlinux running on internal MMC

Source: [Bootloader unlock on samsung arm chromebook](http://krblogs.com/post/63809988096/bootloader-unlock-on-samsung-arm-chromebook).

Please note this method is very risky and can break the device
Copying the steps from blog

Steps:

1. Take a backup of all important data. Anything can go wrong. Have a bootable external mmc ready in case if anything goes wrong
2. Open backcover of chromebook. Follow instructions from ifixit http://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Samsung+Chromebook+11.6+Teardown/12225/2#s45950
3. Next to usb-3 port lies a round ring shape circuit. Remove the stricker from it which will unshort the connection. This will make spi read-write. Make sure there are no traces of metal around it
4. Boot into chromeos. ctrl+alt+T and enter into sudo prompt
   $flashrom —wp-disable
   $flashrom —wp-status

check if write-protection is disabled. If not, go back and clean the circuit. I opened it twice. Download nv uboot image from https://www.dropbox.com/s/6pzvraf3ko14sz9/nv_image-snow.bin.gz (source: Strats’s post at Archlinux forum) gunzip it. You should be having a 4MB bin file. If downloaded bin is corrupt, you might endup with a bricked device. MD5 of extracted binary: CA50D23D315F1378B43E4552D8D441AD

```
// Take backup and then flash
$flashrom -p linux_spi:dev=/dev/spidev1.0 -r orig_image-snow.bin
$flashrom -p linux_spi:dev=/dev/spidev1.0 -w nv_image-snow.bin
$sync and reboot
```

4. Press space on reboot to get into uboot prompt. 
   $setenv bootdelay 1
   $saveenv

   $vboot_twostop          will boot into chromeos
5. Booting custom OS
   format mmc in gpt format. Use cgpt/parted
   create a fat partition for boot, say size 256 MB - mmcblk1p1. Copy vmlinux(or any other kernel) from /boot of chromeos into this partition. Create an ext4 partition for rootfs - mmcblk1p2. copy any linux rootfs. Arch, suse-jeos and fedora worked for me
   Reboot

   At uboot prompt

   // choose 2nd mmc device. Internal mmc is dev 0
   $mmc dev 1

   // ls contents in filesystem. I get lot of dcache warnings. Still works
   $fatls mmc 1:1 /

   // load kernel to memory
   $fatload mmc 1:1 ${loadaddr} /vmlinux

   // set kernel boot parameters
   $setenv bootargs console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk1p2 rootfstype=ext4 rootwait rw

   $bootm ${loadaddr}

   Now you have the freedom to boot any kernel without signing it.

Comment: You need to include the steps from the link in your answer here. It will prevent link rot in the future when that blog changes or removes its content.