# Chromebook ArchLinux install

Tags: linux, arch-linux, chromebook

I can't seem to find any tutorials or instructions for installing arch-linux to a Chromebook, cr-48 specifically.  I've come across many different scripts and stuff that do everything for you, but I really wanna learn hardcore linux and understand it. Hence why I'm trying the Arch Linux Challenge (A little late but what the hell, why not?)
I've seen the instructions here: [is there a way to completely delete Chrome OS on a chromebook - and install linux (not dual boot)](https://superuser.com/questions/662927/is-there-a-way-to-completely-delete-chrome-os-on-a-chromebook-and-install-linu)
But I'd rather not make any hardware changes, unless there's no other option.
Can I wipe the whole system and get it to run of the boot usb and then install it on?
If I can't wipe it, how would I go about repartitioning the system with fdisk? How much space would that leave for arch-linux?
I somewhat of a noob, but I have an obsession with learning, and I want to recontribute to the linux/open source community in the future.

Answer (score 1):

1. Switch the Chromebook off.
2. Remove all thumb drives and memory cards.
3. Switch it on again, then hold down the <kbd>esc</kbd> and Refresh keys and tap
   the Power button.
4. At the recovery screen, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and agree to the prompt.
5. At the Welcome screen, login.
6. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.
7. Type:

   ```
   # shell
   # sudo chromeos-firmwareupdate --mode=todev
   # sudo crossystem dev_boot_usb=1
   ```
8. Reboot.
9. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.
10. Insert the target thumb drive.
11. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>
12. Type:

    ```
    # wget bit.ly/1e6rtI7 -O - | gunzip -dc > alarm.sh 
    # sudo bash alarm.sh
    ```
13. Type `Yes`.
    Wait 5-10 minutes. The script will reboot automatically.
14. At the screen with the big, ugly '!' in the middle, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>.
15. Type `root` when asked for a login ID. There is no password yet.
16. Choose your WiFi connection and enter its password.
17. Wait for the OS to update itself. This will take 30-60 minutes.
     Reboot when prompted to.
18. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>. Login as `root`.
19. This time, type:

    ```
     # wifi-menu mlan0
     # wget bit.ly/1e6rtI7 -O - | gunzip -dc > alarm.sh 
     # sudo bash alarm.sh /dev/mmcbl0
    ```

This should (?) install ArchLinux|ARM on the internal drive.
Your mileage may vary... and it will definitely void your warranty.

Answer (score 0):

There is a guide on the official [archlinuxarm.org](http://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv7/samsung/samsung-chromebook) site. It's specifically for XE303C12, but I guess it should get you started.
There is also something on [craigerrington's blog](http://craigerrington.com/blog/installing-arch-linux-with-xfce-on-the-samsung-arm-chromebook/) that looks rather promising.
I don't have a chromebook (yet), so could not try any of the guides.
Good look, may the force be with you.