# How do I delete chrome OS off my computer

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-os

Can I delete my chrome OS off my Chromebook? If you do know this answer can you explain it to me step by step. If you can it will help me out.

Comment: Why? What are you going to use for an OS on a chromebook?

Comment: You don't need to delete an OS, you just install a different one.  During the installation phase you will be asked to confirm that the disks will be formatted, and this step removes anything off the machine, including the OS.

Comment: If you delete the OS and do noting else, you will have a *brick*. there are cheaper ways to get a brick? What are you ultimately trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 3):

A simple straight answer is a big NO.
But you might want to try out Crouton.

> Crouton: Crouton actually uses a “chroot” environment to run both Chrome OS and Ubuntu at the same time. Ubuntu runs alongside Chrome OS, so you can switch between Chrome OS and your standard Linux desktop environment with a keyboard shortcut. This gives you the ability to take advantage of both environments without any rebooting needed. Crouton allows you to use Chrome OS while having a standard Linux environment with all its command-line tools and desktop applications a few keystrokes away.

If you do decide to take that direction check out this http://www.howtogeek.com/162120/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-on-your-chromebook-with-crouton/.
It provides a step-by-step guide on how to install Crouton.
Then there is ChrUbuntu.

> ChrUbuntu: ChrUbuntu is a Ubuntu system built for Chromebooks. It works like a traditional dual-boot system. You can restart your Chromebook and choose between Chrome OS and Ubuntu at boot time. ChrUbuntu can be installed on your Chromebook’s internal storage or on a USB device or SD card.

You can check ChrUbuntu installation here http://chromeos-cr48.blogspot.fr/.

There is also another way though here [is there a way to completely delete Chrome OS on a chromebook - and install linux (not dual boot)](https://superuser.com/questions/662927/is-there-a-way-to-completely-delete-chrome-os-on-a-chromebook-and-install-linu). Am not sure it worked but if that is your end game, heck go for it. Goodluck.